# Extract words from string before number Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numbers

Hi all I was wondering if it is possible in python to extract words from a string before a number.

For Example:

```
Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test

Hi hazza 60 test test test

hazza 50 test test test
```

I want to get the words before the number not after if it is possible.

```
Hi my name is hazza

Hi hazza

hazza
```

Regards
Hazza

Comment: Absolutely, there are plenty of ways to do this. You might want to look into regular expressions. If there will always be a space before and after the number you could also use `str.split()` and `str.isdigit()` along with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex will do

```
import re

strings = '''
Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test

Hi hazza 60 test test test

hazza 50 test test test

hazza test test test
'''

for s in re.findall('([a-zA-Z ]*)\d*.*',strings):
    print(s)
```

Gives

```
Hi my name is hazza 

Hi hazza 

hazza 

hazza test test test
```

Comment: Quick question, I've been using this to run through my data but I have encountered a problem where some entries don't have a number. Is there any way round this. I have tried using an elif statment to cut the rest of the words if there is a new line.

Comment: The newly edited code should work, try it out @TheAmazingHAzza

Comment: Thanks a lot for the newly edited answer that has helped me a lot. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
is_digit = False
str = "Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test"
r = 0

for c in str:
  if c.isdigit():
     # is_digit = True
     r = str.index(c)

print(str[0:r-2])
```

r is index of 5
r-2 because you want the string without that space before 50

read : https://www.learnpython.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test"
result = ""
for i, char in enumerate(s):
    if char.isdigit():
        result = s[:i]
        break
print(result)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation will allow you to extract all sets of words before each number within your string.

```py
s = '50 Hi hazza 60 test test 70 test'
# Split string on spaces
split = s.split()
# Instantiate list to hold words
words = []
curr_string = ''
for string in split:
    # Check if string is numeric value
    if string.isnumeric():
        # Catch edge case where string starts with number
        if curr_string != '':
            # Add curr_string to words list -- remove trailing whitespace
            words.append(curr_string.strip())
            curr_string = ''
    else:
        # If string not numeric, add to curr_string
        curr_string += string + ' '

print(words)
```

Output:
`['Hi hazza', 'test test']`